# Convert input control to bind to multiple types - Blazor (.net v5)

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Im attempting to create an input element that I can use inside AND outside an EditForm component as Chris Sainty explored [in this excellent blog post](https://chrissainty.com/creating-bespoke-input-components-for-blazor-from-scratch/).
The difference is I would like to create an input that can also be bound to any type.
The following code i tried for the child component:

```
@typeparam T

    <input value="@Value" @oninput="HandleInput" />

@code {

    private FieldIdentifier _fieldIdentifier;

    [Parameter] public T Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<T> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<T>> ValueExpression { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext CascadedEditContext { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression);
    }

    private async Task HandleInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        @* How do I get args into a T type? 
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(args.Value);*@
        CascadedEditContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(_fieldIdentifier);
    }
}
```

But what im struglling with is how can we convert args in the HandleInput function to type T?

Any ideas will be really appreciated!

Comment: I tried your source code both in .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5. It compiles and runs as expected. Can you confirm that the same error happens in a new project as well?

Comment: Thanks @Justthebenno - you helped me figure the issue and ive provided an update in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if this helps anyone else, ive tested a few types including nullables and replacing HandleInput with this works:

```
private async Task HandleInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    T argsValue = (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromInvariantString(args.Value.ToString());

    await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(argsValue);
    CascadedEditContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(_fieldIdentifier);
}
```

Note - you will just need to handle errors converting types.